# Getting RefToDate of the Previous Row to become the RefFromDate of the next Row TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with data on the below format:

```
ProjID   ProjName    RefDate    
-------- ----------- ---------- 
1        A           08/02/2013 
1        A           08/03/2013 
1        A           08/15/2013 
2        B           08/02/2013 
2        B           08/03/2013 
2        B           08/15/2013 
2        B           08/20/2013
```

I want a resultset that looks like below:

```
ProjID   ProjName    StartDate  EndDate    
-------- ----------- ---------- ------------
1        A           08/02/2013 08/02/2013 
1        A           08/02/2013 08/03/2013
1        A           08/03/2013 08/15/2013
2        B           08/02/2013 08/02/2013
2        B           08/02/2013 08/16/2013 
2        B           08/16/2013 08/20/2013 
2        B           08/20/2013 08/22/2013
```

The StartDate is copied from the refdate of the previous row.

How to have a TSQL statement to come up with the resultset mentioned above? I can do an iteration but it's not the optimal way to do it IMHO.

Comment: is there a way to identify univocally a row of the table?

Comment: What do you mean? a unique column ID?

Comment: if the data is unsorted in table how to know which row gonna be next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run SQL2005 or later,  you can

- `self join` to pick the next date
- and `union` the first row for each project

something like this:

```
;
WITH    ProjectDataRanked
      AS ( SELECT   ProjID ,
                    ProjName ,
                    RefDate ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ProjID, ProjName ORDER BY RefDate ) RN
           FROM     ProjectData
         )
SELECT  ProjectData.ProjID ,
        ProjectData.ProjName ,
        ProjectData.RefDate AS StartDate ,
        MIN(ProjectDataNext.RefDate) AS EndDate
FROM    ProjectData
        INNER JOIN ProjectData ProjectDataNext ON ProjectData.ProjID = ProjectDataNext.ProjID
                                                  AND ProjectData.ProjName = ProjectDataNext.ProjName
                                                  AND ProjectData.RefDate > ProjectDataNext.RefDate
GROUP BY ProjectData.ProjID ,
        ProjectData.ProjName ,
        ProjectData.RefDate
UNION
SELECT  ProjID ,
        ProjName ,
        RefDate AS StartDate ,
        RefDate AS EndDate
FROM    ProjectDataRanked
WHERE   RN = 1
ORDER BY ProjID ,
        ProjName ,
        StartDate ,
        EndDate
```

Comment: SQL statement works but changed ProjectData.RefDate > ProjectDataNext.RefDate to ProjectData.RefDate < ProjectDataNext.RefDate

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2005/2008 then you can try this

```
;with cte as
(
  select *,
  row_number() over (partition by projid order by refdate) rn
  from projects
)
select c.projid, c.projname,
coalesce(l.refdate, c.refdate) as startdate,
c.refdate as enddate
from cte c
left outer join cte l 
  on c.projid = l.projid and (c.rn -1) = l.rn
order by 1,3,4
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae7d7/4)

SQL Server 2012 Supports [LAG](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) Function which you can use to achieve same result

```
select 
c.projid, c.projname,
coalesce(lag(c.refdate)
         over (partition by projid 
               order by refdate),c.refdate)
as startdate,
c.refdate as enddate
from projects c
order by 1,3,4;
```

[SQL DEMO for 2012](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae7d7/4)